Serverless function has crashed error on Vercel
Trying to deploy a very simple API request to OpenAI using Vercel, and I keep getting the same error over and over and over again. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? This is the first time I have deployed a code to Vercel, so I am somewhat of a beginner. I have been getting this error over and over and over again for the past couple of hours. Thanks.
import os
import json
import requests
import time
import re
from base64 import b64encode

VERCEL_TOKEN = "YOUR_VERCEL_TOKEN"
OPENAI_API_KEY = "YOUR_OPENAI_API_KEY"

def deploy_to_vercel():
    os.makedirs("api", exist_ok=True)

    with open("api/main.py", "w") as f:
        f.write("""import json
import openai

OPENAI_API_KEY = "YOUR_OPENAI_API_KEY"

openai.api_key = OPENAI_API_KEY

def send_to_openai(transcription, max_tokens=2000):
    try:
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-4",
            messages=[
                {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
                {"role": "user", "content": transcription}
            ],
            temperature=1,
            max_tokens=max_tokens,
            top_p=1,
            frequency_penalty=0,
            presence_penalty=0
        )
        return response.choices[0].message.content
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while communicating with OpenAI: {e}")
        return None

def process_transcription_and_respond(transcription):
    print("Transcription:", transcription)
    gpt_response = send_to_openai(transcription)
    
    if not gpt_response:
        raise Exception("Failed to get a response from OpenAI.")
    
    print("GPT Response received.")
    print("GPT Response Content:")
    print(gpt_response)
    
    return json.dumps({"response": gpt_response}, indent=2)

def handler(event, context):
    try:
        if 'body' in event:
            if isinstance(event['body'], str):
                body = json.loads(event['body'])
            else:
                body = event['body']
            
            transcription = body.get('transcription', "Create the emotion monitoring app as described.")
        else:
            transcription = "Create the emotion monitoring app as described."
        
        result = process_transcription_and_respond(transcription)
        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            "body": result
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            "statusCode": 500,
            "body": json.dumps({"error": str(e)})
        }
""")

    vercel_config = {
        "version": 2,
        "builds": [
            {
                "src": "api/main.py",
                "use": "@vercel/python"
            }
        ],
        "routes": [
            {
                "src": "/(.*)",
                "dest": "api/main.py"
            }
        ]
    }
    with open("vercel.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(vercel_config, f, indent=2)

    with open("requirements.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("""openai==0.27.2
requests==2.31.0
""")

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {VERCEL_TOKEN}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    files = []
    file_list = ["api/main.py", "vercel.json", "requirements.txt"]
    for filename in file_list:
        try:
            with open(filename, "rb") as f_read:
                file_content = f_read.read()
            encoded_content = b64encode(file_content).decode()
            files.append({
                "file": filename,
                "data": encoded_content,
                "encoding": "base64"
            })
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"Warning: File {filename} not found. Skipping.")
            continue

    create_url = "https://api.vercel.com/v13/deployments"
    create_data = {
        "name": "python-openai-app",
        "files": files,
        "projectSettings": {
            "framework": None
        }
    }
    
    response = requests.post(create_url, headers=headers, json=create_data)
    deployment = response.json()

    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Error creating deployment: {response.status_code}")
        print(f"Response: {deployment}")
        exit(1)

    if "id" not in deployment:
        print("Deployment ID not found in response:")
        print(deployment)
        exit(1)

    print("Deployment initiated. Waiting for it to complete...")
    while True:
        status_url = f"https://api.vercel.com/v13/deployments/{deployment['id']}"
        status_response = requests.get(status_url, headers=headers)
        status = status_response.json()
        if status.get("readyState") == "READY":
            break
        print("Deployment in progress...")
        time.sleep(5)

    print(f" Deployment URL: https://{deployment['url']}")
    print(f" Serverless API endpoint: https://{status['url']}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        deploy_to_vercel()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"❌ Network error occurred: {e}")
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"❌ Error decoding JSON response: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"❌ An unexpected error occurred during deployment: {e}")
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()


[ERROR] TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/vc__handler__python.py", line 32, in <module>
    if not issubclass(base, BaseHTTPRequestHandler):INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 1526.81 ms   Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown

